# SFML 2.1 get frame time

Tags: c++, sfml, frame-rate

What is the equivalent of window.GetFrameTime in SFML 2.1?
I think it's from SFML 1.6 or SFML 2.0.
How can I use it in SFMl 2.1 on c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetFrameTime()` was removed from SFML at the beginning of 2012. The reasoning for it can be found here:  http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=6831.0

Users have to create an `sf::Clock` object now and keep time themselves. This has more advantages than disadvantages including:

- Correct time reporting (`GetFrameTime()` reported the time spent during the last frame)
- More control over between which points in your code the time is to be measured
- More control over the precision required

The new way of measuring the update time is 100% accurate (also thanks to the new `sf::Clock::Restart` function)

Code:

```
sf::Clock clock;
...
Update(clock.Restart());
```